# JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token at '{

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

the current hash is

```
{\"report_name\"=>\"Study/Control: ABIRATERONE ACETATE - 20151413355\", \"left_mue_start_date\"=>\"02-26-2015\", \"left_mue_end_date\"=>\"03-19-2015\", \"right_mue_start_date\"=>\"02-26-2015\", \"right_mue_end_date\"=>\"03-19-2015\", \"report_formulary_id\"=>\",7581\", \"mue\"=>\"true\", \"mue_type\"=>\"study/control\", \"chain_id\"=>\"1\", \"left_mue_formulary_ids\"=>[\"7581\"], \"action\"=>\"create_report\", \"controller\"=>\"informatics\", \"user_id\"=>339}
```

now I need to convert it in proper hash like

```
{"report_name" => "Study/Control: ABIRATERONE ACETATE - 20151413355"}
```

so I am trying to get it with JSON.parse but I am getting error like:

```
JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token at '{
```

So if someone know about that so please help me.
 and I am using Rails 3.2

Answer (score 34, accepted):

What you have is a hash printed as String. To convert it into a Hash use [eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-eval).

```
ch = "{\"report_name\"=>\"Study/Control: ABIRATERONE ACETATE - 20151413355\", \"left_mue_start_date\"=>\"02-26-2015\", \"left_mue_end_date\"=>\"03-19-2015\", \"right_mue_start_date\"=>\"02-26-2015\", \"right_mue_end_date\"=>\"03-19-2015\", \"report_formulary_id\"=>\",7581\", \"mue\"=>\"true\", \"mue_type\"=>\"study/control\", \"chain_id\"=>\"1\", \"left_mue_formulary_ids\"=>[\"7581\"], \"action\"=>\"create_report\", \"controller\"=>\"informatics\", \"user_id\"=>339}"
hash = eval(ch)
# => {"report_name"=>"Study/Control: ABIRATERONE ACETATE - 20151413355", "left_mue_start_date"=>"02-26-2015", "left_mue_end_date"=>"03-19-2015", "right_mue_start_date"=>"02-26-2015", "right_mue_end_date"=>"03-19-2015", "report_formulary_id"=>",7581", "mue"=>"true", "mue_type"=>"study/control", "chain_id"=>"1", "left_mue_formulary_ids"=>["7581"], "action"=>"create_report", "controller"=>"informatics", "user_id"=>339}
```

PS: A JSON string should look as follows, meaning what you have is not JSON and hence you got `JSON::ParserError` for using `JSON.parse` on a non-JSON string :

```
"{\"report_name\":\"Study/Control: ABIRATERONE ACETATE - 20151413355\",\"left_mue_start_date\":\"02-26-2015\",\"left_mue_end_date\":\"03-19-2015\",\"right_mue_start_date\":\"02-26-2015\",\"right_mue_end_date\":\"03-19-2015\",\"report_formulary_id\":\",7581\",\"mue\":\"true\",\"mue_type\":\"study/control\",\"chain_id\":\"1\",\"left_mue_formulary_ids\":[\"7581\"],\"action\":\"create_report\",\"controller\":\"informatics\",\"user_id\":339}"
```

Comment: Just be careful using `eval` because it can inject malicious code inside you system depending upon where your hash come from

Comment: true that. `eval` is always risky.

Answer (score 10):

To avoid using `eval` you could use  `JSON.parse ch.gsub('=>', ':')` this way you will get a `HASH` from your `HASH` stored as `STRING`

Answer (score 7):

Last time when I got this issue, since the json file that I got from a API that contains a `BOM`

> UTF-8 BOM is a sequence of bytes (EF BB BF) 
>   [What's different between UTF-8 and UTF-8 without BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom)

at the beginning of that string, but you know that part wouldn't display or as readable when we got the string from response. I try to use Ruby JSON to parse it, but I failed, I got the same exception with yours. just a reminder for others, when you get a Json response. By the way, this would be no problem while you are handling that in javascript, but with problems in Python or Ruby languages.

Comment: Changing the file from UTF-8 BOM to UTF-8 resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, though it was failing while parsing \"\". This is in regards to using Pact.IO. I mention it here since this is the highest ranked Google result while looking for the error I encountered. The solution in my case was to change the body of a POST in my C# application so that it wasn't using empty string, but a null string. Basically I added this before my HTTP call.

```
if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Post && request.Content!=null && request.Content.GetType()==typeof(StringContent) && request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result == String.Empty)
  request.Content = new StringContent(null);
```